# How to do Laravel ORM Relational Databases

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a category table that contains :

```
Schema::create('categories',function($table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name',25);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and product table :

```
Schema::create('products',function($table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    $table->string('name',25);
    $table->text('description');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and product_image :

```
Schema::create('images',function($table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
    $table->string('src',100);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And my models :

Category:

```
class Category extends Eloquent{
    public function Test() {
        return $this->hasMany('Product');
    }
}
```

Product:

```
class Product extends Eloquent
{
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }

    public function images() {
        return $this->hasMany('Images');
    }
}
```

Now I want to show each category in a div with first product photo.

```
Route::get('test',function(){
    $category = Category::all();
    foreach($category as $cat){
        dd($cat->Test->first()->images->first()->src);
    }
});
```

but i receive this error :

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Could any one help me why I get this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed () while calling realtion.

```
dd($cat->test()->first()->image()->first()->src);
```

Comment: i change but still have same error.and also dd($cat->Test->first()); has return NULL

Comment: are you sure there are records in the table? and make sure image table name is images

Comment: also can you try renaming Test() to test() method name should always start with lowercase, its a good convention

Comment: i rename it to test.yes SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images : 2159.and still have same problem

Comment: return of dd($cat->test); is : object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#780 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: still have same problem :((

Comment: i think this surely is the issue. I have edited it again. :)